# How to resolve 504 in nginx server due to high CPU utilization?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, cpu

I am having issue with my server as it goes down after the CPU utilization reaches around 700%(8 core CPU).
The crash happens for around 2 days and again then it comes to normal again after 15-20 days same problem of 504 begins.

I am seeing the CPU utilization as this in [grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVcld.png).

Whenever we restart the server the CPU utilization goes to 700%(8 core CPU) within 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The information provided is very less to find out the issue. Please check your webserver (nginx in your case) logs to find out the exact error when it crashes.

Also, since you are hitting your higher limit of CPU, it might be crashing your webserver but might be fixable. You would need to work on your logs to pinpoint the exact issue.

A simple solution would be to upgrade your server ( in case you are running critical application and want to avoid downtime due to high CPU usage)